# Why do I sometimes see an "Entry 'filename' not uptodate. Cannot merge." after a 'git reset --hard' and a 'git pull'?

Tags: git, merge, reset, pull

Occasionally, when I do the following...

```
git reset --hard
HEAD is now at 0123abde comment is here
```

```
git pull
Updating 0123abde..456789fa
```

I get the error...

```
error: Entry 'filename' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
```

The only workaround I have found is to 'git reset --hard', delete the offending file(s) then do 'git pull'. That doesn't seem right to me. Shouldn't a hard reset remove any and all local changes thus allowing me to pull the latest without any merge issues? Am I using git wrong? :)

This is on a CI machine so any changes here are unwanted. I'm using git version 1.6.1.9.g97c34 on Windows Vista.

Comment: I got this because I had some files I added with --intent-to-add but didn't actually add yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The general idea behind "[`Entry 'filename' not uptodate. Cannot merge.`](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitFaq#head-a188936efde5885e0ff8540c5be897e8029047f7)" is:

> You have changes to files in your working directory that will be overwritten, removed or otherwise lost if the checkout and change to the new branch were to proceed.

It [has been reported](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/12/14/4415044) that this message could be "spurious" at time, (potentially because "`git pull`" [did not refresh the index](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/8/20/3014674/thread) before trying to merge) but the fix was in Git1.6.1.
However, it may still be in mSysGit 1.6.1, so do you see the same error with a more recent mSysGit version ? (like 1.6.3)

---

Before Git 2.30.1 (Q1 2021), "[`git stash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/62fb47a4d3a93d97f4ed82323425135ecd3b84f5/Documentation/git-stash.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash))</sup> did not work well in a sparsely checked out working tree.

See [commit ba359fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ba359fd5070c189f07990c487dc916908830488a), [commit b34ab4a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b34ab4a43ba68dd4bba66d765368a37d99890ab2), [commit a31e48d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a31e48d39429415d2afa35f2c8421482e06a0677) (01 Dec 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 62fb47a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62fb47a4d3a93d97f4ed82323425135ecd3b84f5), 15 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`t7012`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a31e48d39429415d2afa35f2c8421482e06a0677): add a testcase demonstrating stash apply bugs in sparse checkouts
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> Applying stashes in sparse-checkouts, particularly when the patterns used to define the sparseness have changed between when the stash was created and when it is applied, has a number of bugs.
>
> The primary problem is that stashes are sometimes only partially applied.
>
> In most such cases, it does so silently without any warning or error being displayed and with 0 exit status.
>
> There are, however, a few cases when non-translated error messages are shown and the stash application aborts early.
>
> The first is when there are files present despite the `SKIP_WORKTREE` bit being set, in which case the error message shown is:
>
> ```
> error: Entry 'PATHNAME' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
> ```
>
> The other situation is when a stash contains new files to add to the working tree; in this case, the code aborts early but still has the stash partially applied, and shows the following error message:
>
> ```
> error: NEWFILE: does not exist and --remove not passed
> fatal: Unable to process path NEWFILE
> ```

Comment: I'll update to the latest mSysGit. Thanks for the quick and compendious response!

Comment: Just wanted to add that after I updated mSysGit to a newer version, this specific problem never occurred again. So indeed, that was the root cause of my issue.

Comment: I wanted these files to remain in Untracked Files list, hence I was able to get out of this situation with `git rm --cached`. Full comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248029/git-pull-error-entry-foo-not-uptodate-cannot-merge#comment100131900_1248029

Answer (score 67):

The easiest solution I have found to this problem is:

```
git add .
git merge --abort
```

Answer (score 23):

I was having the same issue and I renamed the file which was causing this and did a git pull. It pulled that missing file and fixed the issue.

Answer (score 15):

This also might happen due to using `--skip-worktree` or `--assume-unchanged` commands and git prevent you to do: `checkout`, `merge`, `rebase` or `pull`.

The skipped files/directory might not work if we're doing the following approach:

- `git stash`
- `git merge --abort`, &
- `git rm --cached` this also doesn't work for the `skipped` file this command will throw: `fatal: pathspec [file] did not match any files` instead

Check for the solution for `skipped` files [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49069203/3763032)

```
$: git update-index --really-refresh
<file>: needs update
```

Optional if you want to remove the `skipped` or untracked dir/files on your local

```
$: git reset --hard
```

If none of the above commands fix the issue, you just have to undo the file from `skipped` tree, e.g:

```
$: git update-index --no-skip-worktree [file]
```

If you `skipped` the directory, just go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55860969/3763032) for detail how to skip/undo recursively, e.g:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && pwd && git ls-files -z ${pwd} | xargs -0 git update-index --skip-worktree" \;
```

Comment: THANK YOU! `git update-index --no-skip-worktree [file]` solved my problem when nothing else seemed to work. My eternal gratitude.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue when I was trying to run

```
git merge --abort
```

To get it to work, I staged the changes I didn't want. Once I did that, git was able to successfully undo them.

Comment: I've also had this happen spuriously in response to `git merge --abort`, complaining about an unchanged file. In my case, `git status` caused git to fix itself and I was able to `git merge --abort` successfully afterward.

Answer (score 3):

This error may occur after removing a file from an index with assume-unchanged and then trying to check out another branch.
For instance,

```
git checkout master
```

and even

```
git checkout -f master
```

Results an error:

```
error: Entry 'gradle/apk.gradle' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
```

The solution is to return file back to index with:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged gradle/apk.gradle
```

Then you may finally proceed with a normal checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to `git merge --abort` in a sparsely checked out git repo, none of the solutions worked for me.
Instead I did (assuming I am on branch `my_branch`)

```
git checkout -b BAD_BRANCH  # Switch to another branch
git add -u                  # Stage all the mess
git commit -m "BAD COMMIT"  # Commit all the mess
git checkout my_branch      # Go back to my branch
git branch -D BAD_BRANCH    # Delete branch with all the mess
```