# How do I clone Github data to Amazon EC2?

Tags: github, amazon-ec2

I am new to both Git and Amazon EC2.

I want to clone my Github code to Amazon EC2 directly.

For that I have referred to the following URLs:

http://thelucid.com/2008/12/02/git-setting-up-a-remote-repository-and-doing-an-initial-push/

http://deductiveblog.in/2013/05/19/deploy-to-amazon-ec2-using-git/

[How to push to git on EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632749/how-to-push-to-git-on-ec2)

I've performed the necessary changes suggested in the above URLs, but am still not able to get my data on Amazon EC2.

By following the above suggested steps, I can see one directory - but it does not display the data in it that I have in git & in my local.

So what should I do to clone all data in Amazon EC2?

I also want to know one other thing - is it possible that I can put my files directly in /var/www directory without creating .git?

Now in this, I am getting an error **Permission denied (publickey). Fatal the remote end hung up unexpectedly**.

For that I have checked my **ssh keys** as well and add it to github. I have a file **authorized_keys** for key and I have added the same key in github, but still it gives me a Permission denied error.

Can anyone give any suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: What git command have you used? What repo do you want to clone? What is the instance OS? What is the output of `git --version` when you are ssh'd into the ec2 instance?

Comment: Ubuntu is my instance OS. I Want to clone my Test Repo. When I use git --version command it gives me following output in my local pc: git version 1.8.4.msysgit.0.

Comment: So just clone the git repo to you ec2 instance. git-scm.com/docs/git-clone‎

Comment: It would be appreciated if you provide me an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `git clone` command from your ec2 instance from the directory you want the repo cloned to.

git clone git://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes.git

of course you need to alter the url part to your repo, this will create a folder with the files inside named after the repo in the current directory. If you want to clone the files inside the repo into the current directory do:

git clone git://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes.git .

The Full Stop (.) or dot indicates the current directory in Unix.

Comment: Thanks jeremyjibrown it really helped me.. My problem is solved. I want to ask you one more questions that: Is it possible to clone all files without creating a Repository directory. I mean I want my files of Test repo outside the folder Test directly into /var/www folder as my site is running from there.

Comment: You can just clone from a directory outside /var/www , then if you want any files from your git repo to be served you can copy them or create symlinks.

Comment: I want my files in /var/www. Can you please share one example? It would be appreciated

Comment: Try using the . like above.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have used . at the end of the command. But there is one condition that the current directory must be empty and I have another data in my /var/www directory and I want that data to be remain there and want to clone without folder so use of (.) can not resolve my problem. Can you suggest any other way?

Comment: Hey jeremyjjbrown I am getting an error like permission denied (public key). The remote end hung up unexpectedly. This error is not resolved. Can you help me out in this?

Comment: This error occurs while firing git clone git://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes.git command. First it was working, but now it is giving me an error like permission denied (public key) fatal: remote end hung up unexpectedly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey I have solved my error by generating new SSH key for github and add it to Github account. Now it works for me.