# Configure Git to use a .pem key from a specific location

Tags: git, ssh

Whenever I try to do a 'git pull origin master' I get (It is NOT Github):

> Permission denied (publickey).

I am able to SSH into my AWS EC2 Linux sever, which has the bare repository, which I'm trying to pull from when I get the aforementioned permission error.

I have indeed copied the public key to that server, because I can login successfully via ssh, but only by doing a:

`ssh -i /location/of/pemkey/mykey.pem ec2-user@ec2-12-34-56-78.us-east-compute.amazonaws.com`

I need to configure Git to use my '.pem' key. 
How do I accomplish setting up Git to utilize my '.pem' key?

Comment: Ok why would you configure git to use the .pem key? If you have a generated a ssh key successfully just copy the public key to the server and thats all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `git(1)` man page:

```
   GIT_SSH
       If this environment variable is set then git fetch and git push
       will use this command instead of ssh when they need to connect to a
       remote system. The $GIT_SSH command will be given exactly two or
       four arguments: the username@host (or just host) from the URL and
       the shell command to execute on that remote system, optionally
       preceded by -p (literally) and the port from the URL when it
       specifies something other than the default SSH port.

       To pass options to the program that you want to list in GIT_SSH you
       will need to wrap the program and options into a shell script, then
       set GIT_SSH to refer to the shell script.

       Usually it is easier to configure any desired options through your
       personal .ssh/config file. Please consult your ssh documentation
       for further details.
```

In my personal experience, the one-time cost of adding host settings in `.ssh/config` has made a big difference, even for hosts where only the username is different.

Comment: Good, that is what I thought, but where is my .ssh/config file?

Comment: @ConfusedDeer `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: You got me on the right track and I'll mark your answer as the answer, but I'll add my own answer for clarification, because there are a few other steps that need to be done. I finally got it to pull. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632749/how-to-push-to-git-on-ec2), but it is not the main answer.
The instructions listed here were more useful to me.

Adjust your ~/.ssh/config and add:

```
Host example
Hostname example.com
User myuser
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/other_id_rsa
```

Now use the ssh host alias as your repository:

```
$ git remote add origin example:repository.git

$ git pull origin master
```

And it should use the other_id_rsa key!

Answer (score 4):

```
1. touch ~/.ssh/config
2. chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config
3. vim ~/.ssh/config
    #write next codeline
    host ec2-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
    IdentityFile ~/Documents/ec2-user.pem

git clone git@ec2-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/git/my-repo.git
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `git config core.sshCommand` from git version 2.10.0.
`-c` option can change config temporally.

Command example for cloning.

```sh
git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -i some.pem -F /dev/null" clone ...
```

Reference: https://qiita.com/sonots/items/826b90b085f294f93acf