# centos5 git share folders

Tags: git, centos5, gitolite

i'm new to git and i'm having a problem
i have a problem at pushing data at my git system.
i installed git and gitolite but when i call: "git push origin master" it gives me this error:

```
Counting objects: 12, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 1.47 KiB, done.
Total 12 (delta 1), reused 5 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error:
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To gitolite@server.nl:gitolite-admin
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'gitolite@server.nl:gitolite-admin'
```

i followed this tutorial installing gitolite: [gitolink](http://sites.google.com/site/senawario/home/gitolite-tutorial)
everything worked as i should be but at the very last step. When i execute the command i sadly got this error

can anyone tell me what to do or how to fix this?
already thried :
git config --bool core.bare true
changing the branch (so that it(master) isn't in use)

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot push into git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221859/cannot-push-into-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you're trying to push to a "none-bare" git repository. Whilst this is possible, a lot of the documentation and books don't make it clear that this isn't recommended.

So while git is a decentralised/many-master scm, in practice what you tend to have is "master" or "central" repositories that you clone **from** and push **to** and serve as the "canonical" repo, and work repos (eg on your laptop) that you cloned from a "master" that you pull **to** and push **from**. These "master" repositories should be created with --bare:

```
server$ cd ; mkdir git
server$ git clone --bare /home/user/foo /home/user/git/foo.git
```

Once you've done this, you'll be able to push from your laptop:

```
laptop$ cd foo
laptop$ git remote -v
laptop$ origin user@server:/home/user/git/foo.git (fetch)
laptop$ origin user@server:/home/user/git/foo.git (push)
laptop$ git push origin master
```

You could also do on the server:

```
git config --global receive.denyCurrentBranch "ignore"
```

But I wouldn't do this until you understand better how git works.

Comment: i got the error origin isn't a command
when i skip the lines that starts with origin (go to git push )
i retrieve the error: origin does not appear to be a git repository