# Why I can't push a newly cloned repo?

Tags: git

As I have created a shared repo folder, with path: //web1/www
In another PC, I created a folder, and opened bash, I did:

```
$ git clone //web1/www
```

Then in the new created repo folder:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I added a file and then:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'new file added'
$ git push origin master
```

But, here is what I get the error below, what shall I do now?

```
s.ali@WEB2 /d/ketab projects/www (master)
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 257 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsist
ent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to matc
h
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to

remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into

remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some

remote: error: other way.
remote: error:
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set

remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

P.S: I am on Windows 7 local network, using domain not a workgroup

Comment: From the error it looks like remote git repo @ `//web1/www In another PC` is a **non-bare** git. Pushing onto this remote non-bare repo will result in inconsistency unless you do `git reset --hard HEAD` @ remote repo (as mentioned in error message). Please have a look at [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764380/push-to-non-bare-repository) [posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265729/git-config-receive-denycurrentbranch)

Comment: to elaborate on the above, if the remote is a central store it should be a bare repository.  However, if you must push to a non-bare repository (such as sending changes to a coworker) it is best to push to a new (temporary) branch and merge on the remote repository.  Better yet is to make a new local branch and have the coworker pull the changes, avoiding the push to a non-bare repository.

Comment: Can the console section for `git push origen master` be excised from this question? It looks like that bit was a typographical error, and is not germane to the problem that was being experienced at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your origin is a full repository.

If you want to push to a repo it needs to be a bare one (no working tree)

when creating the repo use the --bare flag

`git init --bare`

the push command only updates the internal git files, not the working directory. so in essence, if you push to a full repo the HEAD (the checked out files in the working directory) will actually be behind the bleeding edge commit you just pushed. So the git developers decided to not allow this.

Answer (score 0):

> git push origen master

Its origin

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: You're not answering the entire question

Comment: The OP's error in using the wrong remote is probably not the point of this question (I have removed it in any case). I will therefore flag this as NAA, as I think this answer goes off on a "typo" tangent.