# Workflow error working directory has unstaged changes

Tags: git, github, github-actions, workflow, git-push

Whenever I am trying to push/merge changes, a workflow in GitHub is getting failed and displays an error that "**Working directory has unstaged changes**";
After committing, it's asking me to push changes; After pushing I receive an error notification on github site;

---

[image: error notification, more info can be seen by clicking on x sign]

---

Below is the code in workflow .github/workflows/dev-deploy.yml .

```
      chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
      git config --local core.sshCommand 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
      git remote add DEV "$DEV_REPO"
      git push DEV
```

Below is the output accessible after either clicking email saying "DEV Deploy: All jobs have failed". it actually executes a workflow, or after clicking on GitHub site notification, it takes us to the workflow. if we click on build it says "Working directory has unstaged changes",

---

[image: workflow build error details]

---

so far I've tried before `git push DEV`;

```
rm -r *
git reset --hard
git read-tree --reset -u HEAD
git restore -- .
```

But nothing seems to be working, it'd be great if someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a:

```
git read-tree --reset -u HEAD
```

To make sure unmerged entries are discarded.

Or:

```
git restore -- .
```

---

Update July 2022:

The GitHub Action [checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout/) includes an interesting test [`__test__/verify-no-unstaged-changes.sh`](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/25a956c84d5dd820d28caab9f86b8d183aeeff3d/__test__/verify-no-unstaged-changes.sh) with the message:

```
    echo "::error::Unstaged changes detected. 
         Locally try running: git clean -ffdx && npm ci && ..."
```

So you can try a `git clean -ffdx` and see if that is enough in your case.

Comment: After adding git read-tree --reset -u HEAD "$1" to my dev-deploy.yml, it is giving below error;
fatal: Not a valid object name 
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.

Comment: @AhmedSyed You can remove the $1 part.

Comment: I have tried by removing it, but still, it did nothing, below is the output;
`echo "Before reset"
  git read-tree --reset -u HEAD
  echo "After reset"
  git push DEV
shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
Before reset
After reset
Warning: Permanently added '[18**' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
To ssh://18**/.repo/
 ! [remote rejected] dev -> dev (Working directory has unstaged changes)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://18**/.repo/'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`

Comment: @AhmedSyed OK, and how about the `git restore` option?

Comment: Same error after using `git restore -- .` , I have simplified my question now, please check once.

Comment: @AhmedSyed Just a thought: is the error message (`Working directory has unstaged changes`) one coming from the remote side? Is `.../.repo` a bare repository, or one with checked out files?

Comment: yes its bare repo, error coming from remote variable defined in DEV

Comment: @AhmedSyed OK, I mentioned it because of https://stackoverflow.com/a/25050788/6309.

Comment: @AhmedSyed I have edited my answer to include a possible solution "from a reputable source".