# git push error on centos6

Tags: git, push

```
git.exe push --progress  "origin" master:master

Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 596 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To (delete by me)
! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to (delete by me)


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (3494 ms @ 2014-10-18 오후 6:20:31)
```

---

My English is terrible.

When I push code to the remote repository, it is showing above error message

what can I do???

(but clone to repository is not problem)

Comment: I did that 'git push origin master'

Comment: Yes I do. same problem.

Comment: use 'git branch' command and show me the results

Comment: * master ||
message is same client and remote server

Comment: it is showing this error 'index and work tree inconsistent'. So for that if two persons working on this project, if any other person push the code. first we have to pull the code do merge then we can push the code.

Comment: thank you comment Anjaneyulu Battula.

Comment: not yet. I think that need a study to me. I don't know 'index and work tree inconsistent'.

Comment: huh~ I search that 'index and work tree inconsistent' in this site.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221859/cannot-push-into-git-repository

and then run command by HaveF answer.
problem is solved.

thank you   Anjaneyulu Battula

Comment: for clarification i added answer for this. if it is helped accept my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git push error '\[remote rejected\] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mainly the problem is because of **'index and work tree inconsistent**. To solve this problem please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221859/cannot-push-into-git-repository)

Comment: Thank you Anjaneyulu Battula. You are very nice guy.

Comment: You should flag the question as a duplicate instead of just linking to a previously answered question on S.O.