# Checking for Git remote hook

Tags: git, hook, githooks

Is there option to check that some kind (I'm interested in `post-receive`) hook is present in some remote repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not remotely from a client.
You need to:

- either have some kind of access to the git [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream/2749166#2749166) with said hook
- or know that the hook is made to display some message that you can parse when you are pushing to the upstream repo.

Hooks are very much *local* to a repo and are [not pushed/cloned around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3703207/6309).
As such, they aren't visible from downstream repos.