# Searching files with pre-commit

Tags: git, terminal, grep, pre-commit-hook

I am trying to add a git pre-commit hook that will check all changed and new file for `TODO:` text.

I tried

```
#!/bin/sh

. git-sh-setup  # for die 
git-diff-index -p -M --cached HEAD -- | grep '^+' |
grep TODO: && die Blocking commit because string TODO: detected in patch
:
```

That i saw in a similar question, but no luck.

Comment: "No luck" isn't terribly helpful diagnostic information.  If something didn't work as you expect, please explain *how* it didn't -- did it output any error message, for example?

Comment: Figured it out. I had copied what was in the `pre-commit.sample` file onto a plain text file, instead of just renaming. Thanks for the help @VonC

Comment: @jesusjjf OK, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, the hook must be in the `.git/hook` folder and name `pre-commit` (with execution right: `chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit`)

The [OP jesusjjf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988272/jesusjjf) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968112/searching-files-with-pre-commit/24968164#comment38810654_24968112) that was the issue:

> I had copied what was in the `pre-commit.sample` file onto a plain text file, instead of just renaming.

Second, here are some script examples:

---

[You have another example](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-git-commit-hooks-to-prevent-stupid-mistakes) using a similar technique, using [`git rev-parse`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) and [`git diff-index`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-index), and the [empty tree I mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9766506/6309):

```
#!/bin/sh

if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    against=HEAD
else
    against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

for FILE in `git diff-index --name-status $against -- | cut -c3-` ; do
    # Check if the file contains 'debugger'
    if [ "grep 'debugger' $FILE" ]
    then
        echo $FILE ' contains debugger!'
        exit 1
    fi
done
exit
```

[The comments on this gist](https://gist.github.com/dcvezzani/3777359) mention:

On my system, `if [ "grep 'debugger' $FILE" ]` always evaluates to `true`.
Changing it to `if grep -q 'debugger' "$FILE"` fixes that.

---

A [more recent example](https://gist.github.com/lsaffie/3266940):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pre commit hook that prevents FORBIDDEN code from being commited.
# Add unwanted code to the FORBIDDEN array as necessary

FILES_PATTERN='\.(rb|js|coffee)(\..+)?$'
FORBIDDEN=( debugger ruby-debug )

for i in "${FORBIDDEN[@]}"
do
  git diff --cached --name-only| grep ".js" |xargs sed 's/ //g'|grep "ha_mobile.debug=true" && \
        echo 'COMMIT REJECTED Found ha_mobile.debug=true references. Please remove them before commiting' && exit 1

  git diff --cached --name-only | \
        grep -E $FILES_PATTERN | \
        GREP_COLOR='4;5;37;41' xargs grep --color --with-filename -n $i && \
        echo 'COMMIT REJECTED Found'  $i 'references. Please remove them before commiting' && exit 1
done

exit 0
```

Comment: Tried the second one with the array of forbidden text, and still not having luck. Does my pre-commit file have to be committed as part of the repo for it to trigger?

Comment: @jesusjjf no: it needs to be in the `repo/.git/hooks` folder, called `pre-commit`, and being executable. Add an echo at the beginning  to check it is executed. Hooks are never committed (or shouldn't: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3703207/6309) or shared between repos (push/pull).

Comment: @jesusjjf by "no luck", I assume the hook is not executed, right? What OS are you on? what git version are you using?

Comment: Don't forget: `chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit` !

Comment: @npc I agree, and I have added that step in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 12):

*This bit loops over the files that are staged, yes, but it then greps the entire file regardless of what portions of it are staged!*

> ```
>    git diff --cached --name-only | \
>        grep -E $FILES_PATTERN | \
>        echo 'COMMIT REJECTED Found'  $i 'references. Please remove them before commiting' && exit 1
> ```

That's no good - don't test strings that aren't staged.

*This solution* tests one or multiple FORBIDDEN strings against **only the staged code, not the entire file**:

## pre-commit

```
#!/bin/bash

RESTORE='\033[0m'
RED='\033[00;31m'
YELLOW='\033[00;33m'
BLUE='\033[00;34m'

FORBIDDEN=( 'TODO:' 'DO NOT COMMIT' 'console.log' 'die' )
FOUND=''

for j in "${FORBIDDEN[@]}"
do
  for i in `git diff --cached --name-only`
  do

    # the trick is here...use `git show :file` to output what is staged
    # test it against each of the FORBIDDEN strings ($j)

    if echo `git show :$i` | grep -q "$j"; then

      FOUND+="${BLUE}$i ${RED}contains ${RESTORE}\"$j\"${RESTORE}\n"

    fi
  done
done

# if FOUND is not empty, REJECT the COMMIT
# PRINT the results (colorful-like)

if [[ ! -z $FOUND ]]; then
  printf "${YELLOW}COMMIT REJECTED\n"
  printf "$FOUND"
  exit 1
fi

# nothing found? let the commit happen
exit 0
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting use of `git show`, more accurate than my answer. +1

Comment: This doesn't seems to work anymore. Trying the colon trick I get the full file content.