# How can I add my pre-commit hook to an existing git repository

Tags: git, githooks

I have a pre-commit hook and I want to add it to the repository so that by checking it out my colleagues have it instantly in place.
However if I try to add it ( being in the root directory of my project) I get the following result:

```
$ git add  .git/hooks/pre-commit
error: Invalid path '.git/hooks/pre-commit'
error: unable to add .git/hooks/pre-commit to index
```

Any idea if this work and how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Git hook scripts be managed along with the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427207/can-git-hook-scripts-be-managed-along-with-the-repository)

Comment: Thanks for answering after 4 years ;) . By now I prefer the solution I added in Dec 2019 using  "brainmaestro/composer-git-hooks"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> checking it out my colleagues have it instantly in place

**Sept. 2015**: That is not possible: a hook can be put in source control (you simply copy the script in your git repo), but it cannot be "automatically in place" (active) on clone/checkout: that would be way too dangerous, depending on what the hook is actually doing.
See also "[Git remote/shared pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3703207/6309)"

You would still need to activate it, by adding a symlink (even on Windows) to the pre-commit hook present in the git repo.

**Update Dec. 2016**: the [OP Calamity Jane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2055097/calamity-jane) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649628/how-can-i-add-my-pre-commit-hook-to-an-existing-git-repository/32649801?noredirect=1#comment69642576_32649801):

> I solved it by now in symfony2 projects (and with others, it also should work) to have it as part of the `composer.json`.
>   So if a colleague is doing a `composer install` or `composer update`, it is automatically placed in the correct place.

```
"scripts": { "dev-install": [ "bash setup_phpcs.sh" ] },
```

> So on dev, `setup_phpcs.sh` is automatically called and that copies the hook from a folder in the repository to the right place.
>   And since the hook is part of the repository it can be easily updated and distributed.

As noted by [Hi-Angel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2388257/hi-angel) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649628/how-can-i-add-my-pre-commit-hook-to-an-existing-git-repository/32649801?noredirect=1#comment98243078_32649801):

> I figured that out: Emacs has `build-aux` dir with hooks, and, upon running `autogen.sh`, all hooks are copied from there.

Comment: With another repository I am using a symlink to a central repository with the effect that half of my colleagues are not using the hook.
But well if it doesn't work that way, then I will have it like with my other repository and I can also understand why this is not desired.

Comment: Thanks for answering *why*, that's what I wanted to know about @VonC.

Comment: By the way I solved it by now in symfony2 projects ( and with other it also should work) to have it as part of the composer.json. 
So if a colleague is doing a composer install or composer update it is automatically placed in the correct place. 

    "scripts": {
        "dev-install": [
            "bash setup_phpcs.sh"
        ]
    },

So on dev setup_phpcs.sh is automatically called and that copies the hook from a folder in the repository to the right place. And since the hook is part of the repository it can be easily updated and distributed.

Comment: @CalamityJane Nice! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: But when I clone e.g. Emacs projects, it has hooks in it, which means somehow they managed to add them.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I suppose magit is adding those hooks: https://github.com/magit/with-editor/commit/87c96b3a7cdf9ab9477e27f1ae2010883a83a426

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out: Emacs has `build-aux` dir with hooks, and upon running `autogen.sh` all hooks are copied from there.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Well spotted. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

If your repository is an [npm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)) application, you can add this nice library as a dependency: [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky/tree/master)

File *package.json*

```json
...
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "husky": ">=4"
},
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
        "pre-commit": "npm test"
    }
}
```

`pre-commit` can be basically any command: if it ends with exit code 0, the commit passes, otherwise the commit is interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP and [PHP Composer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composer_(software)):

FYI, in the year 2019, there is also this option:

Require this package: "brainmaestro/composer-git-hooks"

And add the following lines to your *composer.yaml* file:

```
"extra": {
    "hooks": {
        "commit-msg": [
            "regex=\"^([A-Z]{2,4}-[0-9]{1,4}|(no-ticket|NO-TICKET)):[\\s]*.{10,}\"",
            "file=`cat $1`",
            "if ! [[ $file =~ $regex ]]; then",
            "  echo \"ERROR - Commit message is wrong or too short. E.g. XXX-33: Description or no-ticket : Description\"",
            "  exit 1",
            "fi"
        ],
        "pre-commit": [
            "git status --porcelain | grep -e '^ [AM]\\(.*\\).php$' | cut -c 3- | while read line; do",
            "ROOT=`php -r \"echo __DIR__;\"`",
            "bin/php-cs-fixer fix -nq --config=$ROOT/.php_cs \"$line\";",
            "bin/phpcbf --standard=PSR2 --encoding=utf-8 -n -p \"$line\";",
            "git add \"$line\";",
            "done",
            "echo committing on branch $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the example, which works for me. What it basically does is this:

Every time you run "composer install" or "composer update", the hooks in folder *.git/hooks* are checked. If the hooks are already in place nothing happens. If they are missing, then the lines from above are parsed into the the hooks with a shebang at the beginning. They are then executed each time somebody is triggering a hook.

If you don't have big scripts that is IMO the better solution than copying scripts around.

Note: if you change the lines in the *composer.json* for the hooks, you have to delete the respective hook first before you run "composer install" or nothing will change.

Comment: Oh, shoot, I totaly forgot that only php developers use git...

Comment: You are right, I should have added that this is for php although the use of composer implies it ;)