# Github - Pre commit hook across all projects in organization

Tags: git, github, pre-commit-hook

I would like to set up pre-commit hook in all my projects under my organization . I googled and found I have to do that manually for each project . Is there a way to set up these hooks across all projects under my organization . Also If I can add these hooks automatically when I create new projects will be more helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git remote/shared pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703159/git-remote-shared-pre-commit-hook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place all your hooks in a template directory, you can set up git so that it uses these hooks when creating or cloning a new repo. Only works for client-side hooks though.

You can either use the `--template=/path/to/templatedir` option when using `git-init` or `git-clone` or add the following lines to your `.gitconfig`:

```
[init]
    templatedir = /path/to/templatedir
```

Answer (score 1):

GitHub (almost) only supports client-side hooks (they don't allow you to use your own server-side hooks). Client hooks, like pre-commit, are something you would configure not just for each repo, but for each user's clone of that repo.

When I say "almost" it's because they also support some predefined hooks for "Protected Branches". You may be able to use protected branches and a custom status check to build what you need.