# Git - pull & push - production server

Tags: git, repository, push, pull

I have a production server with git-1.7.3.4_centos5.2 described [here](http://www.krizka.net/2010/12/30/setting-up-a-public-git-repository-with-godaddy-shared-hosting/), and I have a local machine with git 1.7.7.1. What I need is a copy on local server where I can develop the site and upload it to the production server. There is another guy who can modify the content, so I need to pull the changes too. How can I solve that with git? (The most actual code is on my local machine now.)

I made some tests: I cloned an empty repo, and after that I modified the repo on the server. I could not download it with remote/download (git gui), but with checkout I had success. The push did not work also. How can I make them operational?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define two remotes:

> What I need is a copy on local server where I can develop the site and upload it to the production server

That is a simple

```
git clone http://www.your_prod_server.com/git/your_bare_repo.git
```

That will clone the repo and define a remote named "origin". You will be able to push to it because it is a bare repo.
See "[all about "bare" repos -- what, why, and how to fix a non-bare push](http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/bare.html)".
See also "[GIT: after push, remote repo shows files as deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3761891/6309)" for the danger of pushing to a non-bare repo:

> When you push to a remote repo in Git, it does not update the working copy of that remote repo.
>   This means that the working copy will be out of sync with the last version that you pushed.

---

> There is another guy who can modify the content, so I need to pull the changes too.

You need to add a remote pointing to the "other guy's repo address"

```
git remote add otherguy http://otherguy_server/other_guy_repo
```

Even if that colleague's repo isn't bare, you will be able to *fetch* from it, getting back his changes in your repo, and merging them in your local branch.