# fatal: did you run git update-server-info on the server? - Not using github

Tags: git, push, web-deployment, web-development-server

1.
I followed the following tutorial to setup git for web development on my private server.

[Using git for Deployment](http://danbarber.me/using-git-for-deployment/)

Im getting the following error while using

```
git push origin master
```

> fatal: http://mysite.com/.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
>   not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

I followed through various questions on stackoverflow which all points to creating a repository before using git push but i already have a git repository.

2
. When i visit mysite.com/.git , the complete .git repository is displayed. How do i disable this and just enable git push to the same.

Comment: What `git remote -v` does return in your local repo you are trying to push?

Comment: origin http://mysite.com/.git (fetch)
origin http://mysite.com/.git (push)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A remote url like `http://mysite/.git` is certainly not a valid one.

It should refer to a bare repo *name* like, from the tutorial you reference, 'myproject/.git':

```
git remote set-url origin dan@server:/var/git/myproject.git
```

(Replace `dan` by the user account you used to setup a git repo in `/var/www/myproject`).

---

The [OP wdphd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2254360/wdphd) confirms it works, but the non-bare repo isn't updated.

That is because the hook is pushing to "`hub`", and that remote need to be declared:

```
cd /var/www/myproject/.git
git remote add hub /var/git/myproject.git
```

(easier than editing `/var/www/myproject/.git/config` directly)

Comment: Thanks this worked!
I made some changes to my local server and pushed it to my private server. But the changes are still not reflected.

Comment: @wdphd probably because you are pushing to a non-bare repo, which is,'t recommended. You need to `git checkout master` in your server destination repo for its working tree to update itself.

Comment: @wdphd see for why a non-bare repo is not updated by a push: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3761891/6309. And regarding bare repos: http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html

Comment: No, im not pushing into non bare repo. From the tut:
$ cd /var/git/myproject.git
$ git init --bare
$ cd /var/www/myproject
$ git push /var/git/myproject.git master

Comment: @wdphd then it seems normal to not see any file in a bare repo. The `post-update` hook should update the non-bare repo though. Make sure it is executable (`chmod 755`).

Comment: Rechecked the whole code again. It still says everything upto date

Comment: @wdphd and you do have a `/var/git/myproject.git/hooks/post-update` file, executable? And you have a remote named "`hub`" correctly declared? What `git remove -v` returns when executed in `/var/git/myproject.git`?

Comment: Yes, the post-update hook is executable. 

git remote -v in /var/git/myproject.git doesn't return anything. But i have added 

    [remote "hub"]
      url = /var/git/myproject.git
      fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/hub/*

 into `/var/www/html/.git/config`

Comment: @wdphd I have edited the answer to make the necessary steps (regarding the hook) clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the update man. When i try to add the remote hub, it already exists. I'm a beginner in git so please excuse me for this extended discussion

Comment: @wdphd sure, if you already edited the config file manually, you don't have to do a `git remote add`: it would indeed already exist. I was just pointing out the 'git' way to add a remote.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39151/discussion-between-wdphd-and-vonc)