# Who propagate bugfixes across branches (corporate development)?

Tags: version-control, workflow, dvcs

We have many release and custom branches. When bugfix occur it MUST propagated across many branches.

I have several related questions:

- who decide (which role) where propagate bugfix
- who control (which role) bugfix propagation
- where fix bug - in trunk/default or in selected branch?
- is it need test bugfix on all branches by bugfix developer or only on original and pass another branch testing to QA team?
- who propagate bugfix - original bugfix creator or assigned separate person (which role)?

Answer (score 2):

The DVCS aspect is a bit different, because [merging is orthogonal to publication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563836/sell-me-distributed-revision-control/2563917#2563917) (pulling/pushing).

That means you need to distinguish between:

- propagation between branches (merge)
- propagation between repo (pull/push of *public* branches, ie branches made to be replicated amongst repo)

Once you have those branches identified, a bugfix promotion should be initiated by the developer from his/her bugfix branch to the common dev branch, and then published.
The bugfix itself should be fixed in a dedicated branch.

You can setup a guarded commit principle by publishing to a Q/A repo which will pass the test and reject the commit if those fails.
See "[What is the cleverest use of source repository that you have ever seen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209208/what-is-the-cleverest-use-of-source-repository-that-you-have-ever-seen/3209767#3209767)" for examples of pre-tested commits or private builds.