# How can I reject git pushes on an origin repo from a local repo if it does not pass unit tests?

Tags: git, bash, githooks, git-remote

I have an origin repo that I have full access to and I don't want code to be pushed successfully to this repo unless the code being pushed successfully passes my unit tests. I saw many examples of .git/hooks/update scripts and they seem to break down into a few categories that do not fit my use case.

For example, in (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy), the script accesses files locally in the `.git/hooks/` directory (ACL example) or **individual** files in the new or old SHAs.

I need to do an entire build process on all the new files as if I were in the directory of the new commit and were running

## .git/hooks/update

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
mvn test
exit $?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a [guarded commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209767/6309) approach, where you are pushing to an *intermediate* repo, which:

- triggers the mvn test
- push, upon successful completion, to your actual intended repo.

Comment: That sounds like a great approach. Have you used this approach? Any extra considerations or tips while taking this approach?

Comment: @Victor'Chris'Cabral mainly by having a second bare repo, with a post-receive hook in it (similar to your update hook), and a test at the end of the hook to push to the original repo if `mvn test` doesn't return an error.

Comment: Also, is there any way to do this with rejecting the update just in case I want to?

Comment: @Victor'Chris'Cabral reject a commit you have already pushed would mean git revert that commit locally and push it, in order to cancel the previous commit. (last part of http://stackoverflow.com/a/4114122/6309)