# How do i sync/update files using git master stored in dropbox among different computers?

Tags: git, dropbox

I setup my master dropbox repo following the instruction found: http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290743/using-dropbox-git-repository. I was able to create the remote and clone the repo to another computer without any problems.

Now I commit a change in computer B and push it to the dropbox master by

```
    git commit -m "test to see dropbox repo works"  % commit changes to local repo

    git push dropbox master % push to remote master located in the dropbox folder
```

then in computer A I do

```
    git pull dropbox master
```

It shows that it's updated, but I didn't see the changes in the files that i modified? What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You are on the `master` branch in both working repositories?

Comment: yes, I just want to keep both computers synced to the same repository.

Comment: @adjfac: are you sure you aren't in a detached head mode on computer A repo? (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes/1000009#1000009 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin/5772882#5772882 for more)

Comment: @VonC I don't think I am in a detached head mode after reading the two you suggested. When i do 

git pull dropbox master

I now get the error: Entry <blah blah> not uptodate. Cannot merge.
and just quits. Thoughts?

Comment: @adjfac: you need first to make sure you aren't in a detached HEAD mode anymore, ie. `git branch` should display a branch with a '*' in front of it.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I finally just deleted the copy from computer A and did a clone from the dropbox master. That seems to have fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

Although `pull` is convenient, it hides what's actually going on and can make tracking down issues a bit difficult. So, rather than using `pull`, use `fetch` and then `merge`:

```
git fetch dropbox
(if you are not already on master) git checkout master
git merge dropbox/master
```

The advantage of this is that in between the `fetch` and the `merge` you can `log` to see what you've pulled:

```
git log dropbox/master
```

As for your 'entry notuptodate', try [Git pull: error: Entry foo not uptodate. Cannot merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248029/git-pull-error-entry-foo-not-uptodate-cannot-merge).