# having troubles with git pull (embedded linux)

Tags: git, centos, embedded-linux

I am trying to update linux-2.6-xlnx] files with Git pull -command, however I have stumbled on this problem. I get an error msg when I am trying to use the command and I have not got any clue what to do. Would someone please be so kind and tell me what to do.

```
[student@localhost linux-2.6-xlnx]$ git pull
Updating 1f104e3..f04dc68
drivers/staging/rt2860/common/cmm_data_2860.c: needs update
error: Entry 'drivers/staging/rt2860/common/cmm_data_2860.c' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248029/git-pull-error-entry-foo-not-uptodate-cannot-merge

Answer (score 0):

The "not uptodate" message in git is rather confusing - essentially it means that you have some uncommitted changes to that file.  You should either stage (i.e. `git add`) the file and create a commit before pulling, or discard the changes with `git checkout -- drivers/staging/rt2860/common/cmm_data_2860.c`.

This error message is also mention in the git FAQ:

- https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#.22needs_update.22_and_.22not_uptodate.22

(Incidentally, the reason I say that it's a confusing message is that for people who are used to CVS or Subversion, their immediate thought is likely to be, "oh, so I need to *update* - but isn't that just `git pull` in git?")