# Git locally ignore files by file-extensions

Tags: git, git-bash, gitignore, file-extension, git-skip-worktree

I want to locally ignore files by file-extensions. The files are tracked in Git but updated frequently on my machine. They should not be tracked by git anymore (so that `git status` or `git add .` would not be clogged with hundreds of files) but also they should not be deleted on the remote, as a `.gitignore` on the remote would do.

Let's say I have this worktree that has already been tracked by git:

```
.
├── parent
│   ├── child
│   |    └── file1.txt
│   ├── child2
│   |    ├── file2.jpg
│   |    └── child
│   |         └── file3.txt
│   ├── somefile.png
│   └── anotherfile.txt
|
```

How could all `.jpg` and `.png` files be ignored in all subfolders? Alternatively, is it possible to ignore all subfolders with the same name? (e.g. all subfolders named `child`). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55860925/2678563) is a solution for folders and all their contents.

In my understanding, the recursive nature of `git update-index --skip-worktree` would make it necessary that the index is updated after a new file is added and it's not possible to ignore by filename with `*.jpg` or `**/*.jpg`.

I'm using Git-Bash on Windows10.

Comment: You cannot really ignore tracked files, period.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the files are deleted on the remote which I don't want.